# Left join causes huge performance drop. How to fix it

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join, query-performance, sql-server-2017

I have 3 separate queries and when I merge them via left join, the performance drop is huge

Any ideas why it might be happening or how to solve this issue?

Here the queries

**first query**

```
SELECT MONEY,
       AccountLevel,
       BadgeCount,
       EloWin,
       TournamentOfficBattleTotal,
       MaximumTowerLevel,
       NpcBattleVictoryCount
FROM table_2
WHERE table_2.UserId = 465903
```

**second query**

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT table_1.PokemonId) AS PokedexOwnage
  FROM table_1 WHERE UserId = 465903
```

**third query**

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS PokedexEvent
  FROM table_3 WHERE UserId = 465903
```

**and here my solution to merge all 3 into one**

```
  SELECT MONEY,
         AccountLevel,
         BadgeCount,
         COUNT(DISTINCT table_1.PokemonId) AS PokedexOwnage,
         COUNT(DISTINCT table_3.PokemonId) AS PokedexEvent,
         EloWin,
         TournamentOfficBattleTotal,
         MaximumTowerLevel,
         NpcBattleVictoryCount
  FROM table_2
  LEFT JOIN table_1 ON table_1.UserId = table_2.UserId
  LEFT JOIN table_3 ON table_3.UserId = table_2.UserId 
  WHERE table_2.UserId = 465903
GROUP BY AccountLevel,
         BadgeCount,
         EloWin,
         TournamentOfficBattleTotal,
         MaximumTowerLevel,
         NpcBattleVictoryCount,
         MONEY
```

When i compare via execution plan, the first 3 queries take 0% relative cost to the last query

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are providing query plans, [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) is a far better way to do so, than images. Especially when we can't inspect those images and the image doesn't provide the full plan. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate *before* joining.  One method is uses correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT MONEY, AccountLevel, BadgeCount, EloWin,
       TournamentOfficBattleTotal, MaximumTowerLevel, NpcBattleVictoryCount,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.PokemonId)
        FROM table_1 t1
        WHERE t1.UserId = t2.UserId
       ) as PokedexOwnage,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table_3 t3
        WHERE t1.UserId = t3.UserId
       ) as PokedexEvent
FROM table_2 t2
WHERE t2.UserId = 465903;
```

This will probably be fine.  But for better performance, be sure you have indexes on `table_2(UserId, PokemonId)` and `table_3(UserId)`.